# Need to decrypt SAML response

Tags: c#, encryption, saml-2.0

I need to integrate Single Sign On using C# , I get SAML response from IdP and I need to decrypt SAML response (encryption : TripleDes). I need to decrypt using private key in certificate.

When I try to decrypt using certificate key, it gives me error : invalid key size. Is there a standard way to convert private key into valid size for TripleDes ? e.g.

Should I be taking first 24 bytes Or should I be taking MD5 hash ? Are any open libraries available to decrypt SAML response in C# ?

**Below is XML I recieve from IdP:**

```
<saml:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
  <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <EncryptedKey xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
          <X509Data>
            <X509Certificate>Signing certificate goes here==</X509Certificate>
          </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
        <CipherData>
          <CipherValue>Cipher value goes here==</CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
      </EncryptedKey>
    </KeyInfo>
    <CipherData>
      <CipherValue>cipher value goes here=</CipherValue>
    </CipherData>
  </EncryptedData>
</saml:EncryptedAssertion>
```

Code snippet:

```
byte[] inputArray = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedData);
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripleDES = (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
```

Exception comes on second line. I am not using any third party tools currently.

Comment: are you using any libraries for saml?

Comment: No , I am not using any libraries for SAML. I am not aware any SAML libraries for .NET

Comment: Might i suggest locating one?

Comment: Your code does not make sense. What is `EncryptedData`? What is `cert`? Assuming `cert` is certificate - the certificate does not contain private key, so taking one from it using `cert.PrivateKey` is impossible, and even assuming it is possible, casting `cert.PrivateKey` to `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider` does not make any sense too.

Comment: Hi Daniel - yes please suggest locating library.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your code snippet to this:

```
byte[] inputArray = Convert.FromBase64String(EncryptedData);
var cryptoProvider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
```